# How to create executables of py files in python 3.8.5?

Tags: python, executable

How can I generate executables of python files using python's 3.8.5 version? So far I've been having a lot of problems with pyinstaller which only supports until version 3.7. Do I necessarily need to downgrade my python's version? If so, how can I change my python version using windows powershell (without anaconda)?

Comment: Commenting for better reach. Even on 3.7, tensorflow is having issues.

Comment: A couple years back I used py2exe, have you tried that?

Comment: I'll try, but which python version were you using? I've heard py2exe only supported until 3.4, although i'm not sure though. I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: Just confirmed that py2exe doesn't work for python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

try entering

```
    py -0
```

then see what available versions of python you have installed, then just enter py -"version number here" and it should boot up that version